# How to create a cellular automata rule to achieve a desired pattern?

Tags: automata, cellular-automata

Normally, to find the rule that is suitable to our need, we have to generate all possible rules and apply each rule on a seed and check whether a rule produces a desired pattern. This method is exhaustive and computationaly intensive.

Is there a way to derive the rule that would generate the desired pattern?

Comment: With "pattern" do you mean a (single) configuration or an entire time-state diagram?

Comment: I mean entire time state diagram after applying the rule, 'n' times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you describe would be to encode your problem as a [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) instance, with clauses decribing the desired initial and final pattern and the state transitions under the (fully or partly unknown) evolution rule, and then let a generic SAT solver look for a solution.

In fact, at least for certain classes of rules (specifically, [two-state isotropic rules on the Moore neighborhood](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Isotropic_non-totalistic_Life-like_cellular_automaton), a class that includes e.g. Conway's Game of Life), you won't even need to implement this yourself, since there is an existing program called [LLS](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Logic_Life_Search) that can do exactly that.  While a full [tutorial on how to use LLS](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Tutorials/LLS) is beyond the scope of this answer, one of the things it can do is take a partial rule string (i.e. a description of the state transition rule, with some transitions left unspecified) and a list of grids fully or partially describing the evolution of a pattern over several generations, and search for a solution that fills in the unspecified bits of the transition rule and/or the pattern.